# How to return/throw ServiceStack's HttpError using scoped JsConfig?

Tags: c#, error-handling, exception, servicestack

I have multiple API versions that uses the same AppHost, which is why I don't want to modify the static JsConfig--I only want the HttpError response to be serialized using a scoped JsConfig. I tried using:

```
throw new HttpError(statuscode){
    Response = errorResponseDto,
    ResultScope = () => JsConfig.With(...)
};
```

and also attempted using:

```
UncaughtExceptionHandlers.Add(async (req, res, name, exception) =>
{
    await res.WriteErrorToResponse(req, req.ContentType, req.OperationName, "test", new Exception("test2"), 401);
});
```

but not sure how to apply the scoped JsConfig in this case. Am I missing something here? Is this possible at all?

**Add**: if it matters at all, I'm trying to return the error response in camel case, but only for the specific API version which returns responses in camel case as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom scope around WriteErrorToResponse:

```
using (JsConfig.With(...))  {
    await res.WriteErrorToResponse(req)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! But can you tell me why this doesn't work? `throw new HttpError(statuscode){
    Response = errorResponseDto,
    ResultScope = () => JsConfig.With(...)
};`

Comment: @NatashaTheodoraPetrus I've [added a test showing custom scopes working in HttpError](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/a3aa97d22a69ea4a343ecc04727c5ef1be7d601a), so it should work. Maybe upgrade to latest version if not already.

Comment: on a related note, I can't seem to use `using (JsConfig.With(...))  {
   return DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(req, exception);
}`. Wondering why that is--and also how can I force the error response created to be camel-cased?

Comment: @NatashaTheodoraPetrus The scope only lasts within the using statement, creating the Response DTO just creates the object, it doesn't do any serialization itself which is why you must use ResultScope since the scope is used during serialization.

Comment: @NatashaTheodoraPetrus An alternative is to serialize it to a JSON string in your Service (e.g. .ToJson()) and return the serialized JSON string, but then it limits your Service to only being able to be called by JSON and couldn't be used elsewhere Service responses are used.